# Erro ao autenticar Json com php passando header

Tags: php, javascript, json, header

Estou com um pequeno problema ao consultar uma URL com arquivo `JSON`. Basicamente meu código retorna `bool(false)`.

```
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '123';

$header = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($usuario . ':' . $senha) . "\r\n";
          'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8';
opções fornecidas na options predefinição.
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
                  'header' => $header
              )
    )
);
error_reporting(0);
$arquivo = "https://127.0.0.1:9088/xd/servidor/?serie=2018&?number=424";

$info = file_get_contents($arquivo);

var_dump($info);
```

Se eu no lugar da url passar diretamente o nome do arquivo, por exemplo *arquivo.json*, meu `var_dump()` lê normalmente o código, porém para acessar a URL ele não lê.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado